# Содержимое ячейки в таблице JS

Tags: javascript, table

Есть таблица: количество строк зависит от входных данных. В строке 6 ячеек. В 6-ой ячейке checkbox.

Как пройти по всей таблице и проверить выбран ли checkbox в 6-ой ячейке:

```
(function () {

var sendButton = document.getElementById('createTeamButton');

sendButton.addEventListener('click',sendButtonClickHandler);

function sendButtonClickHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var members = [];
    var employeeList = document.getElementById('employeeTable').getElementsByTagName('tr');

    for(var i = 1; i < employeeList.length; i++) {
        //Проверка нажатого checkBox
    }
}

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Почему i = 1? Первая строка заголовок?
for(var i = 1; i < employeeList.length; i++) {
    // Берем 6-ю ячейку в строке
    var td = employeeList[i].querySelectorAll("td")[5];
    // Берем чекбокс
    var checkbox = td.querySelector("input[type='checkbox']");

    // Если чекбокс выбран, то...
    if (checkbox.checked) {
        // Действие
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, первая строка это заголовок